# how to install php7.0-mbstring in debian 9.3

Tags: debian, php7

I can't install php7.0-mbstring:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  php7.0-mbstring :
>   Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.19-1) but 7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.2 is to be
>   installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

sources.list:

```
deb http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ stretch main deb-src http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib

deb http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free deb-src http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
```

`apt-cache policy` output:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=3.1,o=Jamie Cameron,a=stable,n=sarge,l=Webmin,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin download.webmin.com
 500 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.at.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.3,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin debian.man.ac.uk
```

`apt-cache policy php7.0-common` output:

```
  Installed: 7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.2
  Candidate: 7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.2
  Version table:
  *** 7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      7.0.19-1 500
        500 http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @GAD3R There are no files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Mixing stretch and sarge and dotdeb repositories is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have a version of `php7.0-common` from dotdeb, which your list of repositories no longer knows about, and which is preventing you from installing the Debian 9 PHP packages. You should remove that, along with any package depending on it, and install `php7.0-common` from the Debian repositories:

```
sudo apt remove php7.0-common
sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring
```